# How do I guarantee that a name is valid Active directory user?

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

The goal is to extract different properties from an AD (active directory) using LDAP in java, given a list of user-IDs. For this, I have

```
public Map<String, List<String>> UserDetails(List<String> userSAMs){
    DirContext ldapContext = null;
    Map<String, List<String>> detailsMap = null;
    ldapContext = new LdapProp().getLdapContext();
    String returnedAtts[] = {"cn", "givenName", "memberOf"};

    String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(|"; // long OR statement
    for (String sam : listSamids){ // building the LDAP query 
       // HIC SUNT LEONES
       searchFilter = "(" + sam + ")";
    }
    searchFilter = searchFilter + "))";

    NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = ldapContext.search(searchBase, searchFilter, searchCtls);
    while (answer.hasMoreElements()) {  // Loop over results
        SearchResult sr = (SearchResult) answer.next();
            Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();
            String samStr= attrs.get("sAMAccountName").toString();
            samStr.replace("sAMAccountName: ", "");
            List<String> propOfSam = new ArrayList();
            for (String ldapParam : returnedAtts){
                String paramStr = attrs.get(ldapParam).toString();
                paramStr.replace(ldapParam + ": ", ""); // extract value
                propertiesOfSam.add(paramStr);
            }
            detailsMap.put(samStrng,propertiesOfSam);
        };
   return detailsMap;
 }
```

For sake of simplicity, I stripped all error handling in the code. The class `LdapProp` encapsulates all the LDAP-connection details like `PROVIDER_URL` of the AD server, `SECURITY_PRINCIPAL`, `SECURITY_CREDENTIALS`, and the `SEARCH_BASE`.

My issue: **How to I guarantee the sanity of the input list?** The position for that is marked by `HIC SUNT LEONES` in the code.

The list of allowed characters is described in [RFC 1779](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1799) and [RFC 2253](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2253).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I tried so far is to remove all forbidden characters from each string `sam` of the input list using a regular expression. The non-trivial part was how to correctly escape them. I came up with the following work-around: I replaced the line `\\ HIC SUNT LEONES` by

```
sam = sam.replaceAll("[\\\\<>=\\*+-;:\\|@\"\\[\\]\\?]" ,""));
```

Here, the outer square brackets is **character class** within the regex, i.e. `[abc]` means *"any character from a,b or c"*. The tricky part is e.g. that `\\\\` represents simply the backslash.

Comment: I am still looking fo a cleaner way of doing it!